# Is there a way to query CTRun if it includes emoji characters?

Tags: macos, core-text

I'm doing color transformations on glyphs rendered with CTFontDrawGlyphs, but I do not want to  do those transformations to the emoji glyphs, since they have already a meaningful color information.

So, when I have a CTRun of glyphs, can I detect if it is actually emoji/color font?

I can do a string compare to the postscript name with "AppleColorEmoji", but seems awfully wasteful to do all the time, and somewhat hacky if there ever happens to be another font with the same features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, I can get the symbolic traits with CTFontGetSymbolicTraits, and check for kCTFontTraitColorGlyphs (or kCTFontColorGlyphsTrait), which, while undocumented, is available in the public headers.